# How to serve angular with nginx with a relative path

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I'm bit lost on how serve my angular app with nginx. The requirements are that the url for accessing the app will fall under: `www.domain-name.com/rte`

I have the app files on a docker on the path: `/usr/share/nginx/html/`

And my default.conf looks like:

```
  location /rte {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
```

But when I try to access the page, a timeout happens.

I've tried with this aswel:

```
  location /rte/
```

and a 404 is thrown.

Edit: my index.html has -> `base href="/"`

Comment: Sounds like you need to change the `base href` to `/rte/`, or compile the application with the `base href` set to `/rte/` using the `--base-href` option before you deploy. See this: https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: @R.Richards should I use ```/rte/``` or ```/rte```?

Comment: I would try `/rte/` first. It has worked for me without the slashes at all in the past. You may have to play around with it.

Comment: I've tried it and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add /rte/ on `try_files $uri$args $uri$args $uri $uri/ /rte/index.html;`

And as Richards commented, I had to add the /rte/ on the index html base href as well:

base href="/rte/"